# Where do I put an array and a function that I will use through all my program c#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm new to C# (coming from c++). I'm creating a WindowsAplication Form and I use an array (which is filled with a function) through all the program, my question is, Where do I put the function and the array? How do I declare them? I tried declaring them inside my Form1 class but it doesn't work with other forms.

Comment: Show us your attempted code!

Comment: Are you saying that you have currently declared the array in the *class scope* but you actually want to introduce *global state* with this array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set it up as a property of the Form, so you could do something like this:

```
public partial class MyForm:Form
{
    public Integer[] MyArray {get; set;}
    ....


    public void PopulateArray()
    {
        MyArray = ...;
    }
}
```

Then, in some other form, you would simply have something like so:

```
public partial class MyOtherForm:Form
{
    private MyForm myForm;

    public MyOtherForm(MyForm sourceForm)
    {
        this.myForm = sourceForm
    }

    ...

    Integer[] array = this.myForm.MyArray;
}
```

The above assumes that the form which will contain the array will be passed as a parameter. So essentially, the first form, will initialize the second form and will pass a reference to itself, thus allowing you to access any public fields which `MyForm` will expose.

If you will populate this array only once, and will then only read from it, you could use a Helper class to expose the array to all the relevant classes, so you would have something like so:

```
public static class Helper
{
     public static Integer[] MyArray {get; set;}
}
```

Then, in your forms, you would simply do: `Helper.MyArray = ...` to populate and `Integer[] array = Helper.MyArray` to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a public class in put array and function in it. And Where U want to use array and function, U have to create a object of that class and using object u can access array and function.

You can also create a static class and And Where U want to use array and function, U can directly use them without creating object.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could have this array as a public static member of any class in your program. For example:

```
class MyClass {
    public static int[] MyArray;
}
```

Though, preferably, you should use a public static property to access this member.

You then access this variable:

```
MyClass.MyArray = new int[15];
int myFirstElement = MyClass.MyArray[0];
```